# Using Oracle SQL, how does one output day number of week and day of week?

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL, how do you create a result set for:

- Number for the Day Of The Week (1-7)
- Name of the day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.)

For example:

```
DAY   NAME
1     Monday
2     Tuesday
3     Wednesday
4     Thursday
5     Friday
6     Saturday
7     Sunday
```

Comment: This was originally a very poorly worded question. However, it has been edited and clarified and is now a very useful question. The answers on this page were of great help to me with simplifying an (originally) difficult Oracle problem. These answers are not available elsewhere. This question deserves to be re-evaluated and possibly reopened.

Comment: It's a Real Question now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Florin's answer is how I'd do it, but you need to be a little careful about [NLS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch1.htm) settings. The day of the week is affected by the NLS territory, so if I run this as if I'm in the US it works:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'AMERICA';

select to_char(sysdate, 'D') as d, to_char(sysdate, 'Day') as day from dual;

D DAY
- ------------------------------------
6 Friday

select level as dow,
    to_char(trunc(sysdate ,'D') + level, 'Day') as day
from dual
connect by level <= 7;

DOW DAY
--- ------------------------------------
  1 Monday
  2 Tuesday
  3 Wednesday
  4 Thursday
  5 Friday
  6 Saturday
  7 Sunday
```

But the same query run in the UK is a day off:

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'UNITED KINGDOM';

select to_char(sysdate, 'D') as d, to_char(sysdate, 'Day') as day from dual;

D DAY
- ------------------------------------
5 Friday

select level as dow,
    to_char(trunc(sysdate ,'D') + level, 'Day') as day
from dual
connect by level <= 7;

DOW DAY
--- ------------------------------------
  1 Tuesday
  2 Wednesday
  3 Thursday
  4 Friday
  5 Saturday
  6 Sunday
  7 Monday
```

... and I need to adjust the calculation to correct for that:

```
select level as dow,
    to_char(trunc(sysdate ,'D') + level - 1, 'Day') as day
from dual
connect by level <= 7;

DOW DAY
--- ------------------------------------
  1 Monday
  2 Tuesday
  3 Wednesday
  4 Thursday
  5 Friday
  6 Saturday
  7 Sunday
```

You can also specify the language used for the day names separately if you want:

```
select level as dow,
    to_char(trunc(sysdate ,'day') + level - 1, 'Day',
        'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=FRENCH') as day
from dual
connect by level <= 7;

DOW DAY
--- --------------------------------
  1 Lundi
  2 Mardi
  3 Mercredi
  4 Jeudi
  5 Vendredi
  6 Samedi
  7 Dimanche
```

Documentation for [`to_char()` with `nls_date_language`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions198.htm) and [day of the week](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements004.htm#autoId6), and more in [the globalisation support guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1007202).

Comment: this one seems to work for me `to_char(vdate,'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')`

Comment: @TecHunter - I think that still isn't documented (except for Fusion, oddly) so I'd be wary of using it in production code.

Comment: You can avoid all the `NLS_TERRITORY` issues by `TRUNC`ating to the start of the ISO week (which is always midnight on Monday) and offsetting from that. I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970759/1509264) with more details.

Answer (score 4):

When trying to get the day number from a date, you can avoid the issues that the `NLS_TERRITORY` settings raise when using `TO_CHAR(dt, 'D')` and, instead, compare the day to the start of the ISO Week (which is always midnight Monday):

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 1 AS day_number,
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'fmDAY') AS day
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | DAY_NUMBER | DAY |
> | --- | --- |
> | 5 | FRIDAY |

*Note: you can also use `fmDAY` to automatically strip trailing white-space from the day name. If you use `DAY` (without the `fm` modifier) then all the day names will be padded to an equal length; which for English would mean that `Friday`    would be right-padded to the same length as `Wednesday`.*

---

Comparing using the ISO week to using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'GERMANY';

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') AS dn_tochar
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 1 AS dn_isoweek
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | DN_TOCHAR | DN_ISOWEEK |
> | --- | --- |
> | 5 | 5 |

Which is good; as Oracle considers that Germany's week starts on a Monday so Friday is the 5th day of the week.

But the same query in a different territory:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'BANGLADESH';

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') AS dn_tochar
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 1 AS dn_isoweek
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | DN_TOCHAR | DN_ISOWEEK |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 5 |

And does not give the same answer for the `TO_CHAR` version as Oracle considers that Bangladesh's week starts on a Friday so it would be day 1 of their week.

Similarly, amongst other countries, Egypt's week starts on a Saturday and America's week starts on a Sunday so all their values will be off if you use `TO_CHAR`; but not if you use the ISO week.

---

But if you just want to generate 7 rows with each day of the week, then you can simplify the problem and use a hierarchical query to generate the day numbers and then offset the date from the start of the ISO week:

```sql
SELECT LEVEL AS day_number,
       TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + LEVEL - 1,
         'fmDAY',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
       ) AS day
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;
```

Which always outputs:

> | DAY_NUMBER | DAY |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | MONDAY |
> | 2 | TUESDAY |
> | 3 | WEDNESDAY |
> | 4 | THURSDAY |
> | 5 | FRIDAY |
> | 6 | SATURDAY |
> | 7 | SUNDAY |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=71dcb4dbeee5bf73a5b4f0e49b3ae99f)*

Answer (score 2):

```
select level as dow, 
    to_char(level+trunc(sysdate,'D'),'Day') as day
from dual
connect by level <= 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without alter session

```
 CASE 
    WHEN to_char(sysdate, 'd')-1 = 0 THEN 7 
    ELSE to_char(sysdate, 'd')-1 
 END
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Select 1, 'Monday' from dual union all select 2, 'Tuesday' from dual ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there another way without using UNION.