# Start and End Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

First-timer here, please be gentle.

I have this table with start and end dates with amounts. As shown below:

```
Start_Date | End_Date    | Amount
7/1/2015   | 9/30/2015   | 100
7/1/2015   | 7/7/2015    | 200
7/8/2015   | 7/714/2015  | 300
```

I would like to create a query where it would pick up the amount if the start and end dates hits a Wednesday in a quarter. For example, in the first Wednesday of third quarter for 2015, it should the first two amounts, 100 and 200. The second week would be the last two amounts, 200 and 300.

Here is the code I'm testing

`(end_date >= TO_DATE('2015-09-30 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - 7) AND (start_date <= TO_DATE('2015-09-30 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - 13)`

I would then adjust the dates accordingly. This does not work because even though there can be up 14 weeks a quarter, there is only up 92 days per quarter.

Additional information, say the start and end date hits multiple Wednesdays, how can my query be flexible enough to capture it?

Side comment: I am using a program that write SQL query for me. That's why the code is partial.

Comment: Ok, what is your code so far? any 1st attemp?

Comment: Take a look at [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function in oracle docs.  `Select * from This_table where DayOfWeek(Start_date) = 4 and DayofWeek(End_date) = 4` for starters.  if you want quarter, review date functions in above link to help you out.  If you're after something else, an example table structure and data with expected results generally helps elicit a better "answer"

Comment: This should be a good starting point to extract info from dates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx. Sorry, did not notice you tagged Oracle

Comment: The code I am testing: (end_date >= TO_DATE('2015-09-30 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - 7) AND (start_date <= TO_DATE('2015-09-30 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - 13)

Comment: @JorgePadua add it to the question not as a comment (Edit question)  The more effort you show, the more inclined others are to assist you.

Comment: `DayOfWeek` function is from MySQL. According tags it is Oracle not MySQL.

Comment: Doh!  Alternative approach.  Wish they'd specify the DBMS better in the docs then... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517761/using-oracle-sql-how-does-one-output-day-number-of-week-and-day-of-week  I did see mySQL in the bottom right corner of the page...