# What is the syntax for day of week select case?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to use a case select if the day is Monday (or d is equal to 2), and the 'else' would handle every other day of the week.

```
   Select to_char (sysdate, 'D') d from dual,
/*if 2 or Monday then run this part*/
       CASE 
         2
           Then
            SELECT DISTINCT RPAD(CLAIM.CLAIM_NUMBER, 20) ||
                   LPAD(CLAIM.CLAIM_ID, 15, '0') ||
                   TO_CHAR(CLAIM.INCIDENT_DATE, 'MMDDYYYY') ||
                   LPAD(' ',2) ||
                   'D'  
              FROM CLAIM,CLAIMANT,INSURER,POLICY
             WHERE CLAIM.CLAIM_ID = CLAIMANT.CLAIM_ID
               AND POLICY.INSURER_NUMBER = INSURER.INSURER_NUMBER
               AND INSURER.INSURER_NUMBER NOT IN ('7','8')
               AND CLAIMANT.EXAMINER1_CODE NOT IN ('MAYCONV') 
               AND CLAIM.INSURANCE_TYPE = 2
               AND CLAIM.JURISDICTION_CODE <> 1
               AND CLAIMANT.CLAIMANT_TYPE_CODE in (4,7)
               /*if Monday then go 2 days back*/   
               AND CLAIMANT.EDIT_DATE > (SYSDATE - 2)

 /*if not equal to 2 or any day but Monday then run this part*/              
               Else
                 SELECT DISTINCT RPAD(CLAIM.CLAIM_NUMBER, 20) ||
                   LPAD(CLAIM.CLAIM_ID, 15, '0') ||
                   TO_CHAR(CLAIM.INCIDENT_DATE, 'MMDDYYYY') ||
                   LPAD(' ',2) ||
                   'D'  
              FROM CLAIM,CLAIMANT,INSURER,POLICY
             WHERE CLAIM.CLAIM_ID = CLAIMANT.CLAIM_ID
               AND POLICY.INSURER_NUMBER = INSURER.INSURER_NUMBER
               AND INSURER.INSURER_NUMBER NOT IN ('7','8')
               AND CLAIMANT.EXAMINER1_CODE NOT IN ('MAYCONV') 
               AND CLAIM.INSURANCE_TYPE = 2
               AND CLAIM.JURISDICTION_CODE <> 1
               AND CLAIMANT.CLAIMANT_TYPE_CODE in (4,7)   
                /*if not Monday then go 1 day back*/  
               AND CLAIMANT.EDIT_DATE > (SYSDATE - 1)
 /
```

Comment: Side issue, but you should be aware that [NLS settings affect the day number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14518463/266304); someone else running your code in a different locale might see a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't follow your code closely, but it seems you just want the last condition in your `where` clause to depend on the day of the week.

If so, you need something like (WARNING: I didn't check anything else in the code to make sure it is correct or efficient!) - the only change is in the last line. You don't need the `select... from dual` and you only need to write the `select` statement once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT RPAD(CLAIM.CLAIM_NUMBER, 20) ||
                   LPAD(CLAIM.CLAIM_ID, 15, '0') ||
                   TO_CHAR(CLAIM.INCIDENT_DATE, 'MMDDYYYY') ||
                   LPAD(' ',2) ||
                   'D'  
              FROM CLAIM,CLAIMANT,INSURER,POLICY
             WHERE CLAIM.CLAIM_ID = CLAIMANT.CLAIM_ID
               AND POLICY.INSURER_NUMBER = INSURER.INSURER_NUMBER
               ............
 AND CLAIMANT.EDIT_DATE > SYSDATE - case to_char(sysdate, 'd') when 2 then 2 else 1 end
```

Comment: Thanks very much!