# How to retrieve day of a week from date in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Column in a record, which is declared as vPracownik.zatrudniony is in a format like this `12/31/1967, 11:00:00 PM`. I want it to be a parameter of DATEPART(dw, vPracownik.zatrudniony) . It throws an error:
`ORA-06550: line 11, column 13: PLS-00201`.

All code looks like this:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cPracownicy IS
        SELECT *
        FROM Pracownicy 
        FOR UPDATE;
    vPracownik Pracownicy%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    FOR vPracownik IN cPracownicy LOOP
        
        IF (DATEPART(dw, vPracownik.zatrudniony) = 2) THEN
            UPDATE Pracownicy
            SET placa_pod = 1.2 * placa_pod
            WHERE CURRENT OF cPracownicy;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            vPracownik.nazwisko ||
            vPracownik.placa_pod
            );
        END IF;
        
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I have also tried using `((SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE(vPracownik.zatrudniony), 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'DAY') FROM DUAL) = 'MONDAY')` in an IF statement. How to correctly retrieve day from date?

Comment: You can alternatively use `IF TO_CHAR(vPracownik.zatrudniony,'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=POLISH')='CZWARTEK' THEN` or directly use `IF TO_CHAR(vPracownik.zatrudniony,'DAY')='CZWARTEK' THEN` presuming your local language settings, within your code block. Btw, `DATEPART` function doesn't exist in Oracle DB

Comment: What did you discover when you googled 'PLS-00201'?   I see it is "identifier must be declared".  And what identifier is it complaining about?  Well, I'd ask you to cite the source for the documentation of the function DATEPART.  Remember, this is oracle, not ms sql server. In addtion, if your column is not of type DATE, then you have a design flaw.  If it _is_ of type DATE, then it is _not_ in any human readable format, it is in oracle's internal binary format for date/time.

Comment: Excuse me, I've meant today by `CZWARTEK` (thursday), replace that with `PONIEDZIAŁEK` (monday) for the current case.

Comment: The `date` keyword is only valid in a [datetime literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).

Comment: [`if` conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-18777904-23F6-4F6D-8B41-46BABF00BA03) have no brackets.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson The syntax is `IF boolean_expression THEN` and it is syntactically valid to wrap an [`expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/expression.html#GUID-D4700B45-F2C8-443E-AEE7-2BD20FFD45B8) in brackets; so while an `IF` statement does not have it the `boolean_expression` can have the brackets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Oracle SQL, how does one output day number of week and day of week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517761/using-oracle-sql-how-does-one-output-day-number-of-week-and-day-of-week)

Answer (score 3):

First convert string to a valid date value, then apply `to_char` to it - with desired format mask - to retrieve day name.

Something like this:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '12/31/1967, 11:00:00 PM' from dual)
  3  select
  4          to_date(col, 'mm/dd/yyyy, hh:mi:ss am') val_date,
  5  to_char(to_date(col, 'mm/dd/yyyy, hh:mi:ss am'), 'Day', 'nls_date_language = english') val_day
  6  from test;

VAL_DATE            VAL_DAY
------------------- ---------
31.12.1967 23:00:00 Sunday

SQL>
```

---

What is `DATEPART` supposed to be? As far as I can tell, there's no such built-in function ...

Answer (score 0):

From Google translate, "Pracownik zatrudniony" is something like "employee hire date" - is that true?

Checking in Linux:

```
$ d="12/31/1967"
$ date -d $(echo $d|awk -F/ '{print $3 "/" $1 "/" $2}') +%A # DOW
Sunday
```

Checking in Oracle:

```
SYS@ORCL19C> select to_char( to_date( '12/31/1967, 11:00:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY, HH12:MI:SS AM'), 'DAY') day_of_hire from dual;

DAY_OF_HIRE
-----------
SUNDAY


SYS@ORCL19C> set serveroutput on
SYS@ORCL19C> BEGIN
  2  IF rTRIM( to_char( to_date( '12/31/1967, 11:00:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY, HH12:MI:SS AM'), 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' THEN
  3     dbms_output.put_line('This person was hired on a Sunday!');
  4  ELSE
  5     dbms_output.put_line('Not on a Sunday');
  6  END IF;
  7  END;
  8  /
This person was hired on a Sunday!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```