# How to check for a specific date with a CASE statement in SQL in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I am trying to write a statement in OracleSQL which will select the results from either yesterday or the last 3 days according to whether the date in a specific field (column3) is monday.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table
WHERE CASE
       WHEN To_Char(Column2, 'Day') = 'Monday'
          THEN Column3 >= (SYSDATE - Interval "3" Day)
       ELSE Column3 >= (SYSDATE - Interval "1" Day)
    END
Order by Column3 DESC;
```

alternatively

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table
WHERE Column3 >= 
    (CASE
       WHEN To_Char(Current_Date 'D') = 1
          THEN To_Char(Current_Date - 3)
       ELSE To_Char(Current_Date - 1)
    END
Order by Column3 DESC;
```

For clarity, I have a table with many thousands of entries and I need to display only recent results from yesterday or from the weekend. The snippet is meant to read the date of entry from column3 and then either show the last 3 days or yesterday accordingly.

SOLVED: The ultimate code which worked--

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM The_Table
WHERE Column3 >= 
    CASE
        WHEN to_char(Current_Date, 'fmDay', 'nls_date_language = English') = 'Monday'
            THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '3' DAY
        ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
    END
ORDER BY Column3 DESC;
```

Comment: Use single quotes for string and date/time literals. (Double quotes are for _delimited identifiers_, i.e. here `"Monday"` is read as a column named Monday.)

Comment: And what is the question? Threre are only statements in your question and (syntactically incorrect) piece of code with no description of your current issue.

Comment: Simply use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
  SELECT column1, column2, column3
    FROM your_table
   WHERE column3 >=
         CASE
            WHEN TO_CHAR (column2, 'fmDay', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'Monday'
            THEN
               TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '3' DAY
            ELSE
               TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
         END
ORDER BY column3 DESC;
```

- in `TO_CHAR`, include `fm` (otherwise you'll get value which is right-padded with spaces, up to the max day name length) and add language identifier

  ```
  SQL> select 'x' || to_char(sysdate + 1, 'Day') || 'x' result from dual;

  RESULT
  -------------
  xUtorak     x

  SQL> select 'x' || to_char(sysdate + 1, 'fmDay', 'nls_date_language = english') || 'x' result from dual;

  RESULT
  -----------
  xTuesdayx
  ```
- truncate `sysdate` to set it to *midnight*; otherwise, you'll get time component as well. I guess you don't need it

  ```
  SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

  Session altered.

  SQL> select sysdate - interval '3' day result1,
    2   trunc(sysdate)- interval '3' day result2
    3  from dual;

  RESULT1             RESULT2
  ------------------- -------------------
  12.05.2023 09:45:46 12.05.2023 00:00:00
  ```

Comment: Attempting to use your snippet, I get the following error message: 

ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    The identifier name started with an ASCII character other than a
           letter or a number....

Error at Line: 4 Column: 1

I found that there were innapropriate spaces in the snippet and deleted them and then it worked. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: It seems that tool you use (which one is it?) doesn't allow leading spaces. OK, never mind, it was easy to fix. I'm glad if it helped, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970759/2936460), a locale independent way of checking for the day of week, is using the ISO week:

```sql
SELECT
   Column1,
   Column2,
   Column3
FROM Table
WHERE
   CASE
      WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') = 0
      THEN Column3 >= (SYSDATE - Interval "3" Day)
      ELSE Column3 >= (SYSDATE - Interval "1" Day)
   END
ORDER BY Column3 DESC;
```